# Need a mature, documented RBAC implementation for Python

Tags: python

I am looking for an RBAC solution that meets the following criteria:

1. It is lightweight. Our requirements are fairly dynamic at this
   point. I don't want to implement a monolithic beast only to find out
   that our (future) customers don't need it.
2. Python. Our default language is Python so a Python solution seems
   ideal.
3. Established. We have been burned previously by using open-source
   software that wasn't ready for prime time. We found out the hard way
   when we realized there were a total of 3 git issues and no mention
   of the software on Stackexchange. Oops. So we want to use software
   that other people are using and that is actively being maintained.
4. Well documented
5. Friendly to SQLAlchemy and Postgres

I have seen simple-rbac and rbac. Both fail multiple items above.

EDIT - we found no RBAC solution that suited us. We wrote a tiny version. Then as requirements increased and became more solidified, we switched the implementation to Neo4J which is superb for this sort of thing. We were already using Neo4J for other things so moving the RBAC to it was not a big deal at all.

Comment: Hey @Tony. Would you be great if you could share what you found useful for the problem at hand.

Comment: @TasdikRahman updated.